# Syntax errors in if/else statement

Tags: c#

I am very new to c# and while working on a basic program I am receiving this error(Error Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement) and cannot figure out why it is appearing.

```
if (pizzaDiameter >= 12 && pizzaDiameter < 16)// begin nested if statement
{
    Console.WriteLine("A" + pizzaDiameter + "will yield 8 slices.");
}
else if (pizzaDiameter >= 16 && pizzaDiameter < 24)//Second pizza diameter range
{
    Console.WriteLine("A" + pizzaDiameter + "will yield 12 slices.");
}
else if (pizzaDiameter >= 24 && pizzaDiameter < 30)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A" + pizzaDiameter + "will yield 16 slices.");
}
else (pizzaDiameter >= 24 && pizzaDiameter <= 30)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A" + pizzaDiameter + "will yield 24 slices.");
}
else // pizza diameter was not a whole number
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pizza diameter must be between 12-36 inclusive.");// Error appears here.
}
else //pizza diameter must be between 12-36
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pizza diameter must be a whole number.");
}
```

Comment: Your first `else` should be an `else if`, or you should remove the conditional statement.

Comment: I have reindented your code to show the actual indentation levels. There are two `if`s missing.

Comment: Thank you, I've been staring at this for an hour unsure of what the problem was :)

Comment: I left out the other if's from this post

Comment: you can use only one `else` as it defines all other probabilities. So in your code the first else is missing an `if` and the other two will work togather as one `else`.

Comment: The line `else (pizzaDiameter >= 24 && pizzaDiameter <= 30)` makes no sense. Maybe `if` is missing, but then it would be redundant with previous `if`.

Comment: @Dialecticus The first check is obsolete, but the line still makes sense IMO.

Comment: @Mario the line will not compile. One `if` is missing there.

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong with your control structure, i.e. you've got only one `if()`, but three times `else`.

Also, try to think about the problem and you'll notice that you can simplify the whole structure significantly (and also skip many checks):

```
if (pizzaDiameter < 12) // All diameters below 12 will use this branch.
    Console.WriteLine("Your pizza seems to be too small.");
else if (pizzaDiameter < 16) // You don't have to ensure it's bigger than 12, since those smaller already picked the branch above.
    Console.WriteLine("A diameter of " + pizzaDiameter + " will yield 8 slices");
else if (pizzaDiameter < 24) // Again you won't have to care for less than 16.
    Console.WriteLine("A diameter of " + pizzaDiameter + " will yield 12 slices");
// ...
else
    Console.WriteLine("Your pizza seems to be too big.");
```

Comment: It's part of the code from my assignment, and was specifically told to do the ranges, but I see why it makes more sense the way you did it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong adding those checks - it will still work - but based on your compiler you're doing more checks than necessary. And considering the obsolete nature of those, it's no premature optimization (plus it really depends on your actual implementation). If you're doing `if()` only, without `else if()`, then you'll need all the checks.

Comment: Perhaps it's to make it more noticeble in what order the code is executed inside a method, there are more then one way to code these types but in assignments you are usually forced to pick a less natural way.

Comment: @user1501127 Perhaps. It's more natural to write it like that, and probably part of the whole "write down your problem first, then optimize it" to get someone new to programming started.